# formatting a number with SI prefix change in version 4

Tags: d3.js

Before version 4

```
var formatter = d3.format("s");  
    formatter(400000) // 400k
```

In version 4

```
var formatter = d3.format("s");  
    formatter(400000) // 400.000k
```

Is there any way I can get the format like previous versions without using precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way I can get the format like previous versions without using precision?

Without using precision, this is not possible anymore in D3 v4.x.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/master/README.md#format):

> Depending on the type, the precision either indicates the number of digits that follow the decimal point (types f and %), or the number of significant digits (types ​, e, g, r, s and p).

Meaning that, for `("s")`, the precision indicates the number of significant digits.

And here comes the interesting part, that doesn't exist in D3 v3.x API:

> If the precision is not specified, it defaults to **6** for all types except  (none), which defaults to 12. (emphasis mine)

So, the precision for `formatter(400000)` defaults to 6, which gives you:

```
400.000k
```

For instance, if you do `formatter(40)`, you'll get:

```
40.0000
```

**PS**: Trailing zeros in a number containing a decimal point *are* significant.

Comment: @Gerado Furtado Is this a bug? The trailing zero doesn't mean anything to me here.

Comment: It's not a bug: trailing zeros in numbers with decimal point *are* significant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures#Identifying_significant_figures