# D3 Format 's' in version 4

Tags: d3.js

Im converting from d3 version 3 to version 4. And i don' understand how to fix a problem. Introduced by the change to the format 's'

Version 3

```
d3.format('s')(14000) //14K
d3.format('s')(4000) //4K
d3.format('s')(4000.10) //"4.0001k"
```

Version 4

```
d3.format('s')(14000) //14.0000k
d3.format('s')(4000) //4.0000k
d3.format('s')(4000.10) //"4.0001k"
```

This also behaves strange ( guess the significant digit change)

```
d3.format('.0s')(14000) //"10k"
```

I would like to show zero decimals and the K if in the thousands.

Note: [formatting a number with SI prefix change in version 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41262922/formatting-a-number-with-si-prefix-change-in-version-4) doesnt answer the question on how i can do the same thing now.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for SI-prefix with two significant digits, that specifier would be:

```
d3.format(".2s")(14000)
"14k"
```

How about:

```js
var v = 14000;
console.log(d3.format("."+ v.toString().match(/[1-9]/g).length +"s")(v));
var v = 4000;
console.log(d3.format("."+ v.toString().match(/[1-9]/g).length +"s")(v));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The only difference with that seems to be `d3.format('.2s')(4000)
// "4.0k"`
Which i guess i can live with..

Comment: @Tim, I guess you could count the non-zeros to guess at the significant digits; see above.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for the `~` option:

```
d3.format("s")(1500);  // "1.50000k"
d3.format("~s")(1500); // "1.5k"
```

It was added in d3-format 1.3.0: https://github.com/d3/d3-format/releases/tag/v1.3.0